# RSYSLOG Relay - Tag incoming logs

Tags: logging, rsyslog

I am setting up an RSYSLOG relay server.  I'd like to only relay those logs received from a remote system to a destination server.  I've found examples of tagging logs that come from a local directory, but nothing for incoming logs from a remote system.  Ideally I don't want to keep any logs on this relay, but just pass them directly to the destination log server.

```
if $fromhost-ip=='192.168.1.10' then /var/log/app1/app1.log

module(load="imfile" PollingInterval="10") #needs to be done just once

# File 1
input(type="imfile"
      File="/var/log/app1/app1.log"
      Tag="app1:"
      Severity="Informational"
      Facility="local7")

if $syslogtag == "app1:" then @@192.168.1.50:1514
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: This configuration seems to work, but I am not 100% confident its forwarding everything.  Could anyone critique this configuration?

Comment: I think the "@" style uses udp. You might prefer reliable tcp. See the [omrelp](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/relp.html) module, and `imrelp`, or use `omtcp`, `imtcp`.

Comment: You are correct.  I updated the @@ last night.  I am seeing traffic but I would expect to see more volume.